# Low screen brightness after instaling NVIDIA drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, brightness

Firstly, sorry for my English.

I use HP Victus 15 Gaming with 3050 Ti.

I installed Ubuntu 22.04. Then, I installed NVIDIA drivers.
But screen brightness decreased substantially. I set max brightness but still low.  Before installing the drivers, there was no problem.
I have Dual-Boot (Windows 11 and Ubuntu). Windows hasn't got the problem.

I edit /etc/default/grub file.

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"

Doesn't fix.

I edit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf file.

Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"

Doesn't fix too.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: You say you edit files but need to add what you added to each file. We can not guess what you did.

Comment: I added "Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"" to "10-nvidia.conf" file

Comment: And I added GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='linux" to grub file

Comment: Please EDIT the question with the edit function and add this info to the question. Also include what file you are adding the info too. Thanks.